# Android screenshot - How to?

Tags: android, screenshot

Is there any neat way of accessing screenshot of android device 
programatically. I am looking for some 15-20fps.

I found one code 
`android\generic\frameworks\base\services\surfaceflinger\tests\screencap\scr eencap.cpp`, 
i built the executable and put it in /data and changed the mode 777

but when i tried to execute it using adb shell it gives the below error.

```
# chmod 777 test-screencap 
chmod 777 test-screencap 
# ./test-screencap test 
./test-screencap test 
screen capture failed: Function not implemented
```

I also know that we can access fb0 but its not a right method as suggested 
by android team. Is it possible to access the screen shot at the frameworks 
layer. I beleive surface flinger composes individual layers and gives it to 
framebuffer.Where exactly this is done ? Can a application be able to access 
such codes.

There are some java apps also which use ddms to actually capture this 
framebuffer data without root access. But the fps is really poor.

I beleive there should be some or the other way of doing the above job. 
Please suggest me some neat way of doing it. Suggestions are welcome.

Comment: So are you trying to write a phone app that is trying to take screen shots of the phone or is this for a PC program taking screen shots of the phone while connected via usb?

Comment: It is a phone app.through which i want to get a screenshot.

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to do is not possible if you don't have a rooted phone, there is an app out there that does what you are trying, [Screenshot ER](https://market.android.com/search?q=screenshot%20er&so=1&c=apps).  The latest OEM's are putting it into their /system/apps now... so you may be able to use their apps, check out this [article](http://Samsung%20Galaxy%20S%20II%20Built-in%20screen%20capture,%20no%20root%20required) for devices that have enabled this feature.  Other than that your really stuck but there are implications with screen captures enabled as this could lead apps saving screen captures and sending that info out, enabling virus type apps...

*Information for others* .....Through Eclipse you can get a screen capture usig the DDMS perspective.  If you take a look at the Eclipse DDMS code base its actually a stand-alone app too.  You might be able to use this Java code then.

```
AdbHelper.getFrameBuffer(AndroidDebugBridge.getSocketAddress(), this);
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [droid VNC Server](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.onaips.vnc&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsIm9yZy5vbmFpcHMudm5jIl0.)
This is an open source project which you can clone the source code to your private PC. (http://github.com/oNaiPs/droid-VNC-server). I am investigating how VNC can do but It's really hard to do the same.

[Read framebuffer content](http://www.pocketmagic.net/?p=1473) is an good solution also. But it just work with android <3.x only. I don't know how to fix it to work on android 4.x. If you know how (after see my suggestion) please share it here. Through my researching, I see that there are a lot of people looking for this.

Hope this helps.
nguyenminhbinh1602@gmail.com.
Android Freelancer.

Comment: Update: On android 4.x (maybe on android 3.x also), the fb0 just contains the image of device when boot. I mean that after boot, the dev/graphics/fb0 does not contain exactly screen content any more.